# Choosing a shard key for a hosted wiki system

Tags: mongodb, sharding, nosql

Say our project is a hosted wiki service. Each company stores its wikis at our servers and users from each company only ever accesses their own company's wikis. These wikis have pages, and each page has a revision history.

Now, a few MongoDB noob questions:

1. What would be a good shard key for this sort of information?
2. Can I choose a shard key so that it is guaranteed that all of a company's data will always be managed by one shard (assuming of course no company has more data than one shard can hold)?
3. How can the choice of shard key guarantee that all servers are equally loaded? e.g. if I shard by the company name and some companies have more wiki data than others, then I'll have some shards very busy while others not.

Comment: have you checked out the docs on sharding and choosing a shard key? http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Introduction and http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Choosing+a+Shard+Key

Comment: Of course. But I couldn't find an answer to these questions, or maybe I just didn't understand it well enough. That's why I'm looking for expert answers here.

Comment: Sorry...didn't mean to state the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

To really understand sharding, beyond what is documented on the mongo.com site, read this book, it's short, but very informative and provides great examples...

[Scaling MongoDB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449303218)

Comment: Thanks, but it seems this book contains just 4 pages on choosing a shard key. :/

Comment: That's true, but it outlines the principals over choosing the right shard key...other books don't even cover shard keys. Here's a decend read on shard key strategies http://tebros.com/2010/11/choosing-a-mongo-shard-key/